# Secured NiFi won´t comunicate with NiFi Registry

Tags: apache-nifi

I have standalone secured NiFi 1.12.1 in Docker running all fine. I am sucessfully using Site-To-Site remote processors, Site-To-Site forwarding of Nifi bulletins, calling NiFi API for self-monitoring and such things. I log in through certificate. So far all fine.

Problem crops up when I try to use [NiFi Registry](https://hub.docker.com/r/michalklempa/nifi-registry). I have access to two instances: secure and insecure.

No matter what exact format I specify (FQDN, just a name, with /nifi-registry or without), when I try to access (e.g. though importing a process group) the *either* NiFi Registry from NiFi, it fails with `o.a.n.w.a.config.NiFiCoreExceptionMapper org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to obtain listing of buckets: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Returning Conflict response.`. In logs is just this message with [enormous stack-trace](https://pastebin.pl/view/54b15774) and nothing more.

I checked all certificates and they seem OK (certification path, certificate is for clientAuth as well as for serverAuth). I even use them to log into NiFi myself...
What surprises me the most is the fact, that it works for things like Site-To-Site protocols, API calls and such, but not for NiFi Registry.

Please don´t you know what might be a problem? Or any ideas what to check?

Answer (score 0):

### TL; DR:

Use IP addresses or edit `/etc/hosts`. Problem is in translation of hostname to IP address.

---

When I attempted to access the API of NiFi Registry directly from NiFi through InvokeHTTP, I noticed an important thing - nothing in different container responded to me (`failed to connect` to target):

```
#Safe NiFi - the one I am troubleshooting
https://<my FQDN>:8443/nifi-api/flow/registries

#Safe NiFi Registry (another container) - the one I am trying connect to
https://<my FQDN>:18443/nifi-registry-api/buckets

#Unsafe NiFi (another container) - just for test
http://<my FQDN>:28080/nifi-api/flow/registries

#Unsafe NiFi Registry (another container) - just for test
http://<my FQDN>:38080/nifi-registry-api/buckets
```

Then it dawned on me: To solve problem with Site-To-Site connections (discrepancy in name of container vs HTTPS certificate issued for hosting machine) I gave the *container* the same name as the hosting *Docker machine*. To verify I used IP addresses instead of FQDNs and it worked. Also checking `/etc/hosts` confirmed this - the FQDN pointed to IP address of container instead of Docker host.

Thus, one given FQDN was in container resolved as localhost and as Docker host everywhere else. And since on localhost on the NiFi Registry port(s) nothing listen ...

So as a solution either mangle the /etc/hosts to remove the offending line, or use IP addresses to force traversing through the Docker host.